# django allauth ImportError at /admin/ No module named context_processors

Tags: django, django-allauth

When I add:

```
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
```

In templates settings of `settings.py` while configuring allauth as given in tutorial of http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial/. I get following error:

```
ImportError at /admin/
No module named context_processors
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.9.2
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named context_processors
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py in import_module, line 37
Python Executable:  /home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/home/pratyush/Documents/blogie/trydjango19/src',
 '/home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/pratyush/Documents/trydjango19/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 24 Jun 2016 17:12:06 +0000
```

However, I am doing exactly same thing as described in the tutorial. Here is my `settings.py` files.

```
"""
Django settings for trydjango19 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'l+@3wk1uwi%j0we$)-6pvs)=o^-td2f@0=w3ifx!-9p2smp7f)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [] #'*'

#ADMINS = (('pratyush','electrifyingpratyush@gmail.com'),)

#EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
#EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
#EMAIL_PORT = 25
#EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
#EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
#EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
#DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'pratyush <electrifyingpratyush@gmail.com>'
# Apsplication definition

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'crispy_forms',
    'markdown_deux',
#    'whoosh',
    'pagedown',
    'posts',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )


CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK='bootstrap3'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'trydjango19.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
                "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'trydjango19.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]

SITE_ID=2

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")

MEDIA_URL="/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media_cdn")

#whoosh_index=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "whoosh")
#import os
#HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
#    'default': {
#        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.whoosh_backend.WhooshEngine',
#        'PATH': whoosh_index,
#    },
#}
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'publish_stream'],
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk'  # instead of 'oauth2'
    }
}
#SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
#            'google':
#        {   'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
#            'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' } }}
```

Comment: yes with little changes ,thanks for guiding !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a three year old tutorial that you are reading. Things have changed.

> ```
> 0.22.0 (2015-07-23)
> Backwards incompatible changes
> Dropped support for Python 2.6 and Django <1.6.
> The default Facebook Graph API version is now v2.4.
> Template context processors are no longer used. The context 
> processor for allauth.account was already empty, and the context
> processor for allauth.socialaccount has been converted into the {%
> get_providers %} template tag.
> ```

What this means is that you sould remove `allauth.account.context_processors.account` and  `allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount` from your settings.py